# Using php code with Spring with Quercus

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, resin, quercus

I am working on a Spring-MVC application where I would like to integrate some Legacy PHP code. In the PHP files, I have mostly static content, and I would like to import and use the PHP tags of include and include once inside a JSP file. After research I came upon using Quercus for this task. Unfortunately I cannot find many references or examples where they would like to import PHP files directly. I can show how is the code I have, can anyone tell me how to import the PHP files. Thanks :

JSP file :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<head>
    <title>Title of page</title>
</head>
 Now here is where I have such PHP code :
<?php
$thisPage="impressum";
include("php/top.php");
include("php/header.php");
include_once("php/analyticstracking.php");
?>
```

I don't have that much knowledge of PHP, so this might seem noobish, but how achieve the above include with Quercus. I have the war already installed.